# Sending ethers with mocha.js and truffle might result in larger sums than intended

Tags: truffle, testrpc, testing, library, mocha

Good day,

I have a contract General and a library GenLib.

```
library GenLib{
    event MoneyIn (address _from, uint256 _amount);
    function moneyIn() {
       MoneyIn(msg.sender, msg.value); <- Only call the event MoneyIn()
   } 
}

contract General{
    function getMoney () payable{
        GenLib.moneyIn();
   }
}
```

Now the weird part, when I'm trying to send money to the General contract using the `getMoney` function, the amount that is actually transferred is TWICE the amount that is specified.

That's the JS file I'm using to check my contract:

```
var Gen   = artifacts.require("General");

contract('Gen', function(accounts) {

  var user = accounts[0];

  var valueP2C      = web3.toWei(2, "ether");

  it("Deploy Gen contract", function(){
    return Gen.deployed().then(function(instance){
      gen = instance;
    });
  });

  it("Gen account is empty", function(done){
    web3.eth.getBalance(gen.address, function(err, res){
      done(assert.equal(res.valueOf(), 0, ""));
    });
  });

  it("Use account is full", function(done){
    web3.eth.getBalance(user, function(err, res){
      userAmount = res.valueOf(); 
      done(assert.equal(res.valueOf(), 0, ""));
    });
  });  

  it ("Send money from user to gen", function(done){ 
    gen.getMoney({from: user, value: valueP2C}).then(function(res){
        done(assert.notEqual(res, null, ""));
      });
  });


  it("Gen recieved money", function(done){
    web3.eth.getBalance(gen.address, function(err, res){
      done(assert.equal(res.valueOf(), valueP2C, ""));
    });
  });

  it("User account is P2C lower", function(done){
    web3.eth.getBalance(user, function(err, res){
      done(assert.equal(res.valueOf(), userAmount - valueP2C, ""));
    });
  });  
});
```

And the final results:

```
✓ Deploy Gen contract
✓ Gen account is empty
✓ User account is full
✓ Send money from user to gen
1) Gen received money
> No events were emitted
2) User account is P2C lower
> No events were emitted


expected '4000000000000000000' to equal '2000000000000000000' <-TWICE THE AMOUNT
expected '87641250800000000000' to equal 89643554700000000000
```

Another piece of information that might be useful is that whenever I remove the call to the external library, everything works just fine.

I'm baffled by this weird behavior and would appreciate any help or insight you might have.

Comment: This bug is still there for me with testRPC 4.0.1
Has anyone found a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite right to be baffled - the behaviour you observe is wrong.

This is an open issue with testrpc, and as you say it is related to the calling of a library function:
https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/122

Sorry I couldn't be of more help - you can keep an eye out on the issue for when it is fixed officially!

Answer (score 1):

It has been fixed in latest [4.1.0 release](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/releases/tag/v4.1.0)